# How to round in Javascript/Angular JS -- but remove insignificant digits

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a the following statement in my Javascript controller:

```
$scope.myList = [0, 1, 0.5, 0.6666666];
```

My AngularJS template contains the following line:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in myList">{{i}}</div>
```

This produces the following HTML output:

```
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>0.5</div>
<div>0.6666666</div>
```

I want the numbers to be rounded to 2 decimal places. **However, I would like to see only significant digits in the output. I don't want to see trailing zeroes.** How do I do it? Using `{{i | number:2}}` doesn't eliminate trailing zeroes.

Comment: round to two places, then convert to a true number again

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="i in myList">{{(i | number:2)*1}}</div>`

Comment: `[0, 1, 0.5, 0.6666666].map(function(el){ return el.toFixed(2); }).map(Number)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could just multiple by 1 to convert it to true value.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in myList">{{(i | number:2)*1}}</div>
```

As noted from the comments above solution will break due to the locale formatting by angular number filter. If you need the locale formatting and rounding you could create an extension filter which underneath uses `number filter` and `$locale` service.

```
.filter('numberEx', ['numberFilter', '$locale',
  function(number, $locale) {

    var formats = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
    return function(input, fractionSize) {
      //Get formatted value
      var formattedValue = number(input, fractionSize);

      //get the decimalSepPosition
      var decimalIdx = formattedValue.indexOf(formats.DECIMAL_SEP);

      //If no decimal just return
      if (decimalIdx == -1) return formattedValue;


      var whole = formattedValue.substring(0, decimalIdx);
      var decimal = (Number(formattedValue.substring(decimalIdx)) || "").toString();

      return whole +  decimal.substring(1);
    };
  }
]);
```

And use it as:

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in myList">{{i | numberEx:2}}</div>
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myList = [0, 10000.56, 0.5, 0.6666666, -1000.23123, 1, 1002, 2.5, 30.5, 22];

}).filter('numberEx', ['numberFilter', '$locale',
  function(number, $locale) {

    var formats = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
    return function(input, fractionSize) {
      //Get formatted value
      var formattedValue = number(input, fractionSize);

      //get the decimalSepPosition
      var decimalIdx = formattedValue.indexOf(formats.DECIMAL_SEP);
      
      //If no decimal just return
      if (decimalIdx == -1) return formattedValue;

 
      var whole = formattedValue.substring(0, decimalIdx);
      var decimal = (Number(formattedValue.substring(decimalIdx)) || "").toString();
      
      return whole +  decimal.substring(1);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in myList">{{i | numberEx:2}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm   quite cool actually. Had to think about it for a minute to figure out why it works.

Comment: "*1" and "-0" are handy ways to convert number types in almost any scripting language, without knowning the particular built-in method to explicitly do so.

Comment: This doesn't work when the number is >1000 since angular will add commas to it

Comment: @YangLi brings up a good point.
`Number(2000.5.toFixed(2))` and `+2000.5.toFixed(2)` both evaluate to the correct answer from the Javascript Console in Chrome. However, when I embed them in my Angular template, neither of them work. `(200.5 | number:2) * 1` works through my template but fails with 2000.5 for the reason Yang Li mentioned.

Comment: This is because the number filter converts the number into a string and if it's greater than 1000 it will add a , to it.  Now when you do "1,200" * 1, it won't recognize the comma.  Hence you need to either remove the comma or use a filter that doesn't convert to a string with a comma.

Comment: oops yeah i missed it. But you cannot use @yangli answer as well it will break based on locale change. It is too hardcoded. I will update an answer considering the locale as well. But if you really do not want to format using number filter i think you should just use @_inorganik answer.

Comment: Fyi, my numbers in actually are percentages. So they will always be between 0 an 100. So although multiplying by 1is a bit hacky because it fails for numbets over 999, it is good enough for my purposes for now. I would prefer that than having to write my own filter.

Comment: @SaqibAli #1) `multiplying by 1is a bit hacky because it fails for numbets over 999` No you got it wrong it is because of the number filter it happens, it puts locale char (eg:- `,`). It is not that it does fail for number above 999. It can happen even if you use `Number(x) or - etc..` :D

Comment: The (X * 1) part is genius. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I would do it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in myList">{{formatNumber(i)}}</div>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.formatNumber = function(i) {
    return Math.round(i * 100)/100; 
}
```

Comment: or return +i.toFixed(2);

Comment: @dandavis he said he doesn't want trailing zeros.

Comment: Having to write an extra function in my controller for this simple task seems like overkill

Comment: What he means is he prefers to not write a filter. @SaqibAli   However, using the Number filter from angular will not achieve this. I presume you are using {{(i | number:2)*1}}, try to set your number to 1000, you will get some major errors.

Comment: @dandavis - yes, it does. That is exactly what `toFixed` is for. http://jsfiddle.net/deqrL4yw/

Comment: @inorganik: you left out the "+" in your fiddle. if you use my code, then you will see "2"... http://jsfiddle.net/deqrL4yw/1/ ; not a typo ;)

Comment: @dandavis I stand corrected - I'd never used a "unary" operator before. Why didn't you add an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers didn't really work well, or did not not incorporate or work with Angular's $locale service, I wrote the following `filter`:

**Template:**

```
<span>{{yourNumber | roundTo: N}}</span>
```

**Filter:**

```
app.filter('roundTo', function(numberFilter) {
    return function(value, maxDecimals) {
        return numberFilter((value || 0)
            .toFixed(maxDecimals)
            .replace(/(?:\.0+|(\.\d+?)0+)$/, "$1")
        );
    }
})
```

---

- Rounds the number to the max number of decimals
- Trims all trailing zero's
- Removes the decimal seperator when it's not needed
- And **Uses Angular's $locale formatting**