# Remove trailing zeros from a number inside AngularJS interpolation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know there are answers for plain JavaScript code for this question but they are not available in this case.

I have a table which must be populated with data. My code looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.matrix[0] track by $index">
    <td>{{$ctrl.labels[$index]}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="label in $ctrl.xMatrix">{{$ctrl.matrix[$index][$parent.$index].toFixed(2)}}</td>
</tr>
```

As it can be seen, it is used `toFixed(2)` to remove all but two digits after dot.

I want also this change:

```
34.90 => 34.9
 0.00 => 0
```

As it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number), I `parseFloat(n.toFixed(2));`, so in my case it would be:

`{{parseFloat($ctrl.matrix[$index][$parent.$index].toFixed(2))}}` or

`{{$ctrl.parseFloat(matrix[$index][$parent.$index].toFixed(2))}}`

but in both cases I get no error and my table is empty.

Is there a way to  remove these zeros inside `{{}}`?

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number

Comment: @Daniel that's what I've used. not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove insignificant trailing zeros from a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number)

Comment: did you read my question? I already put a link to that question and explained why it does not work for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round in Javascript/Angular JS -- but remove insignificant digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850765/how-to-round-in-javascript-angular-js-but-remove-insignificant-digits)

Comment: Did you read further in the comments. It has to be a number to work, cast as a number and then apply the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simple use **number** filter of Angular Js

```
{{$ctrl.matrix[$index][$parent.$index] | number}}
```

OR

Use **$eval**

```
{{$eval($ctrl.matrix[$index][$parent.$index])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you cast your number as a "number". Then cast as a string.

```js
var numberstring = "1.2350000";

var number = Number(numberstring);
console.log(typeof number);

var zerodown = number.toString();
console.log(zerodown)
```

To change numbers inside {{}} is unlikely. This is a placeholder for variables that are dynamically applied. You should do that server side or after the value is parsed.